# GIT stash not deleting new files

Tags: git

I have added some new files in the repository. Made some changes to existing files ,  deleted few files etc..

when I issue `"git stash"`  , I expect all my local changes to be reverted and I should have clean working copy of my remote repo.  But the files I have added newly are still showing up in the "git status".   I have deleted the files manually.

why is it so?   Do i have to issue `"git reset"` ?

**To replicate:**

1. Go to git bash.
2. cd  repo
3. touch abc.txt
4. rm -rf existing.txt
5. git stash
6. git status

Assuming abc.txt is new file created.  When I do "git stash" , the file is still present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/835561/2944723) might help you.

New files are untracked, and by default, `git stash` will not include them. So, you need to run `git stash --include-untracked` or `git stash --all` to stash everything.

Be aware that you might end up stashing ignored files with `git stash --all` command.

#### Update

Another way (maybe easier) to solve this problem is to move unstaged changes to stage area:

Running `git add path/to/file` or `git add .` makes git start tracking these files. Then just run `git stash` and it might do the magic.

Comment: This maskes more sense and easy i suppose .. Adding to index and then doing stash.  git add path/to/untracked-file  ,
git stash

Comment: I think it's difficult  to  remember  the entire command  --include-untracked.. I feel  doing git add and then git stash is bit easy..  But  I am somehow convinced that GIT is making the developers to force learn the commands.

Comment: Yep. You're right. I forgot about it. I'm going to update the answer to include this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reset` but then your changes will be lost & change of mind won't do you any good but with `stash` you can get them back using `git stash pop`.

**Reason for why git stash doesn't stash *untracked files*:**
By default, running git stash will stash:

- changes that have been added to your index (staged changes)
- changes made to files that are currently tracked by Git (unstaged changes)

But it will not stash:

- new files in your working copy that have not yet been staged
- files that have been ignored

So now the question remains: how does one use git stash.

> **TL;DR** Two ways to use stash
>
> - Add the -u option (or --include-untracked) tells git stash to also    stash your untracked files so that our command becomes `git stash -u`
> - You can include changes to ignored files as well by passing the -a    option (or --all) when running git stash & our command takes the shape `git stash -all`

Check out this [article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash) for more details.