# Git - discard added files

Tags: git

Seems like this should be super-simple but looking around for a simple (or half-way straightforward) solution seems impossible:

Say I add a bunch of files to a Git project. 
"git status" now says:

```
# On branch master  
# Untracked files:  
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)  
#  
#   Classes/FileA.h  
#   Classes/FileA.m  
#   Classes/FileB.h  
#   Classes/FileB.m  
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I then decide I want to discard these files and get back to my original status within the project. Do I have to delete each file before proceeding?!!

I've tried:

```
git checkout master
```

which gives "Already on 'master'" and

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

but my added files are still there for both methods.

I've been through the entire Git tutorial (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html) plus various man pages.

Why is this so difficult to do?!!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673407/how-do-i-clear-my-local-working-directory-in-git

Comment: This is also a very good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090316/366064

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
git clean
```

should do the trick. By default, this requires the `-f` flag to really do anything.

Comment: git 'clean' ? Wow, I didnt know that. Thanks!

Comment: Neither did I; I just googled it using "git delete untracked files" ;) First rule of git: if you can think of it, git can do it.

Comment: Note that it recursively removes all files not under version control, so be sure it's what you want.

Comment: `git clean -f -d` removes untracked files. `git clean -f -d -x` removes untracked and ignored files.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the git tip:

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

```
new file:   src/main/java/com/bbva/zic/commons/rm/core/convert/support/BooleanToStringConverter.java
new file:   src/main/java/com/bbva/zic/commons/rm/core/convert/support/BooleanToStringConverterFactory.java
modified:   src/main/java/com/bbva/zic/commons/rm/core/convert/support/StringToDtoIntCollectionAgreementBillConcept.java
```

laura:bbva-commons charly$ git reset HEAD src/main/java/com/bbva/zic/commons/rm/core/convert/support/BooleanToStringConverter.java
laura:bbva-commons charly$ git reset HEAD src/main/java/com/bbva/zic/commons/rm/core/convert/support/BooleanToStringConverterFactory.java
laura:bbva-commons charly$ git status
On branch INC0287
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

```
modified:   src/main/java/com/bbva/zic/commons/rm/core/convert/support/StringToDtoIntCollectionAgreementBillConcept.java
```

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
src/main/java/com/bbva/zic/commons/rm/core/convert/support/BooleanToStringConverter.java
src/main/java/com/bbva/zic/commons/rm/core/convert/support/BooleanToStringConverterFactory.java
```