# git discard specifically changes in the staging area

Tags: git, git-stash

There are cases where I want to discard all the files currently in the staging area and only the files currently in the staging area. Essentially I want something that is just like *making a commit and then immediately discarding the commit that was just made*.

Right now in practice I mostly use `git stash` for this purpose and just remember that I don't actually want the thing that I'm stashing.

However, `stash`ing and discarding are not really the same thing and `stash` appears to capture all the tracked files, not just the ones currently in the staging area, as the script below shows.

Is there a way to *completely discard* (changes to) exactly the files that are currently in the staging area?

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ./a

echo foo > ./a/foo
echo bar > ./a/bar
(
    # add initial commit
    cd ./a
    git init
    git add foo
    git add bar
    git commit --message='initial commit'

    # change first line of foo and bar
    ed ./foo <<'EOF'
s/$/ aaaaaa/
wq
EOF
    ed ./bar <<'EOF'
s/$/ aaaaaaa/
wq
EOF

    git add ./foo
    git stash save
    git status
)
```

When run, this script produces the following output

```
$ bash gitrepo.sh
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/git/a/a/.git/
[master (root-commit) a8f0104] initial commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 bar
 create mode 100644 foo
4
11
4
12
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: a8f0104 initial commit
HEAD is now at a8f0104 initial commit
```

I've also tried essentially the same script with `git clean -f` and `git reset` in place of `git stash save`

`git clean -f` appears to discard neither the changes to `foo` nor to `bar`.

```
[master (root-commit) 0c10b47] initial commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 bar
 create mode 100644 foo
4
11
4
12
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   foo

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   bar
```

`git reset` in this specific case appears to simply remove `foo` from the staging area.

```
[master (root-commit) 65fce7b] initial commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 bar
 create mode 100644 foo
4
11
4
12
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       bar
M       foo
```

The current best solution I have so far is the following script, which has the right behavior in the few cases I've tested it with. However, it accomplishes this behavior by creating, committing to, and then deleting a new branch named by a UUID. I'd prefer a way of discarding the changes in the staging area that's less circuitous.

```
#!/bin/bash

branch="$(python -c 'import uuid; print(str(uuid.uuid4()))')"
git checkout -b "$branch"
git commit -m "commit for $branch"
git checkout -
git branch -D "$branch"
```

When using `gitdiscard` (the script above), the tester script produces the right results, foo's change is discarded, but the unstaged modifications to `bar` are still there.

```
[master (root-commit) e4e81d9] initial commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 bar
 create mode 100644 foo
4
11
4
12
M       bar
M       foo
Switched to a new branch 'abebe893-e579-4ecc-9422-6c99051d67f6'
[abebe893-e579-4ecc-9422-6c99051d67f6 05916d5] commit for abebe893-e579-4ecc-9422-6c99051d67f6
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
M       bar
Switched to branch 'master'
Deleted branch abebe893-e579-4ecc-9422-6c99051d67f6 (was 05916d5).
```

Non-exhaustive list of similar but non-duplicate questions:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3103939/) is not a duplicate because it refers to discarding untracked files, not changes in the staging area.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673407/how-do-i-clear-my-local-working-directory-in-git) is not a duplicate because it refers to clearing the entire working directly, not to discarding changes in the staging area.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree) covers untracked files and untracked directories, but doesn't cover discarding changes to files in the staging area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider the [`--keep-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-push-p--patch-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--ltpathspecgt82308203) flag for `git stash`

It does, in fact, *the contrary* of what you're asking for : it stashes everything **but** what's in the index.

You could take advantage of this and stash only the unstaged changes, then reset your index and working tree, and finally re-apply the stash.

(I'm unsure of how you want the untracked files to be dealt with, but there's also the stash flag `--include-untracked` to keep in mind as a possibility. Use it on the first stash if you need to *include them* in the final result)

```
git stash --keep-index [--include-untracked]
git reset --hard
git stash apply
```

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that when `git status` says:

```
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

this does not mean that the staging area is *empty*.  In fact, the staging area is *perfectly full:* every file *in* the staging area matches every file in the current (or `HEAD`) commit.  Meanwhile every file in the staging area *also* matches every tracked file in the work-tree.

> Is there a way to completely discard (changes to) exactly the files that are currently in the staging area?

Consider `git reset`, `git checkout`, and—in Git 2.23 (which I have not yet used) `git restore`:

- The `git reset` command has a mode in which it copies one file from the current commit, i.e., `HEAD`, to the index / staging-area, without touching the work-tree at all:

  `git reset -- file`

  The `--` is only needed if the file name *`file`* resembles a branch name or a `git reset` option, e.g., if you have a file named `master` and you want to make the staged version match the committed version, `git reset master` is wrong but `git reset -- master` is right.
- `git reset HEAD` does exactly what you've asked for here: it copies every file from the `HEAD` commit into the staging area, so that no changes are staged.
- If you would like the work-tree copy of the file updated as well, one of the many modes of `git checkout` does precisely that:

  `git checkout HEAD -- file`

  As before, you need the `--` only if the file name resembles a `git checkout` option.  For instance, if you want to discard staged and/or unstaged changes to a file named `--patch`, `git checkout HEAD --patch` is wrong but `git checkout HEAD -- --patch` is right.  (Since you have to specify `HEAD` here, `git checkout HEAD master` works to throw out staged-and-unstaged changes to a file named `master`.  However, it's safer to get in the habit of just using the `--` every time.)
- As before, you can check out *every* file from the current commit, but this time it requires using the fact that checkout out a *folder* (directory) name causes Git to check out the contents of that folder recursively, so:

  `git checkout HEAD -- .`

  does the trick, though you need `.` to refer to the correct level of your work-tree.

In Git 2.23, the new [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore/) command gives you the ability to overwrite index, work-tree, or both copies as you like.

**Remember, Git keeps *three* active copies of each file at all times.**  The committed `HEAD` copy cannot be changed—it's in a commit and commits cannot be changed—but it can be accessed with `git reset` and `git checkout HEAD`.  The index copy—also called the staging copy—can be overwritten at any time by:

- copying from `HEAD`: now no changes are staged, or
- copying from the work-tree: now whatever is in the work-tree is staged.

The work-tree copy is a plain ordinary file, so you can do whatever you want to it; but various forms of `git checkout` will overwrite it at your request.

Comment: I've had the impression that OP wanted to get rid of the currently staged changes entirely, not just unstage them... what did I miss?

Comment: I think I messed up the terminology because I'm conflating the "staging area" and "the delta between the staging area and the work tree". I should be more specific. I think what I want to do is take every file that's dirty (in the sense that the versions in the work tree and the staging area do not match)... and replace the contents of those files with whatever's in HEAD ... in both the staging area and the working copy.  I included a script that performs this type of "discard".

Comment: *and replace the contents of those files with whatever's in HEAD ... in both the staging area and the working copy* - that's `git checkout HEAD -- <files>`. You might want to collect a list of these (staged) files' names first, using, e.g., `git ls-files -m`.

Comment: I tried messing around with `git ls-files -m -d -z` to do this, but did not succeed in getting it to list the new files as well. At some point I figured my question was too long already and decided not to include anything about using `git ls-files` to generate candidate paths. Also I couldn't figure out how to handle renames (or stuff that `git status --short` reports to the user as renames).

Comment: Renames are detected, rather than recorded: `git status` always has rename detection turned on and set to 50%, but `git ls-files` never does rename detection at all. To control rename detection you need to run `git diff`, which is more annoying for parsing. Note that `git ls-files -z` uses NUL-termination to protect weird file names, which works well with `xargs -0` (or coding in languages like Python) but is otherwise a bit awkward.

Comment: The `-d` flag of `git ls-files` shows files that are present in `HEAD` but not in the index now: `git checkout` of those files would put them back in the index (matching the `HEAD` copy), as would `git reset`. If by "new files" you mean files that are tracked but not present in `HEAD` (have a `git diff` status of `A`dded), they're a bit problematic since there *isn't* a `HEAD` copy to copy. You'd have to handle those separately.

Comment: Note that rename detection produces odd results at a times: a file named L before and R after is a candidate for rename detection—and then detected as one—if, in a diff, L is present in the left and absent in the right (L is deleted) and R is absent in the left and present in the right (R is added). Git compares the *contents* of L and R at this point and assigns a similarity index. Repeat for all "vanished" and "appeared" files, pair up the "best matches", throw out any matches that fall below the threshold (50% by default), and you have the renames.

Comment: This means that if you add a *new* file named L, after having actually renamed L to R, Git just matches left-side L against right-side L and says "L modified, R added". *Remove* the file named L from the right, and Git goes back to saying that L has been renamed to R.