# How can I revert my last changes with git?

Tags: git, github

I messed up badly my code and I want to revert it to the last commit.

I'm doing `git status` and I see that I changed a lot of files. I don't want to see them at all. So I did `git log` and found out the hash of last commit.

I used this hash in command: `git fetch origin this_hash` and got the message:

```
Mig-macbook-air:ios M$ git fetch origin this_hash
From https://github.com/linkto/myrepo
 * branch            this_hash -> FETCH_HEAD
```

but then when I do `git status` I still see broken files, also I see them in my IDE. I want to completely get rid of those changes, how can I do it?

I didn't do push on the last commit; I just created a branch and did a commit.

Comment: Did you read [How do you discard unstaged changes in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/52704/218196) and [How do you undo the last commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/218196) or [Revert Git repo to a previous commit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/218196) . If yes, why do these solutions not work for you? If no, why didn't you search first?

Comment: Easy: https://xkcd.com/1597/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: undo all working dir changes including new files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090309/git-undo-all-working-dir-changes-including-new-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see all the files when running `git status`, that means you have a lot of local changes that are **not** committed. If you are sure you want to get rid of those changes, run `git reset --hard head`.

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` just fetches more commits from a remote; it doesn't touch the working directory.

You want `git checkout <commit-reference>`, which will check out that version into the working directory.

Answer (score -1):

You have several options to do it:

Read here all about the several ways how to do it:
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)