# How to give up unstaged changes

Tags: git

I made some changes on my local machine and I don't want to keep them.

When I perform a **pull** to get the recent changes from the server I get a message saying that I have unstaged changes and I must commit or stash them.

But I don't want to do it. I want to cancel them. How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: undo all working dir changes including new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090309/git-undo-all-working-dir-changes-including-new-files)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`git checkout .` to undo all non-commited changes on tracked files.

`git clean -f` to remove non-commited files.

PS: `.` in `git checkout .` is shell wildcard that means "*all files within current directories and subdirectories*". You can use any wildcard or path (`git checkout path/` or `git checkout ./*.py`)

Comment: .. or you can replace '.' with the name of the thing you want to revert so you can preserve other changes.

Comment: @DaleWilson fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
git reset --hard
```

Will revert your repository to a clean state.

`git reset <commit>` Will change the index to point at that commit, by default it's HEAD, so your most recent commit.

The `--hard` flag will also revert any files to what they were at that commit.