# Repull changes in git

Tags: git

I made a mistake and i pulled down changes, and i closed my text editor and did save all. So, all the changes got overwritten. Is there anyway to undo my changes or force a repull and overwrite my changes?

Please?

Comment: I think all tags besides `git` are redundant or not applicable here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into:

```
git reset --hard
```

The general idea is to reset your local repository to HEAD. Any tracked files will be replaced with the ones in HEAD.

Comment: So, if i do this, it wont erase any changes in my past commit tho, right, just reset to that point? i.e. 1. Commit. 2. pull. 3.**ck up and erase all pulled changes. 4. git reset --hard 5. All files equal to my #1. 6. Pull again, and everything is fixed! Right?

Comment: @Oscar It will reset to the commit that is HEAD. In your example, that is probably a commit created at #2, so you won't need to "repull", and you won't lose any local commits.

Comment: To be precise though, if you committed 1 but you never *pushed* it, then those changes would be lost. It would be more like

1. Commit. 2. pull and push 3. mess up files 4. git reset --hard

Now it would be as if you had just finished step 2.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, most files are now reflecting the HEAD, whereas some random subset (whichever you had open in your editor) is based on commit $OLD_COMMIT plus your changes.

To throw away all your changes and force your working copy to reflect the HEAD, simply do `git reset --hard`.  If you want to salvage your edits, here's what you can do:

First, find out which files got changed by your text editor using `git status`.  Then, run `git reflog` to figure out the SHA1 of $OLD_COMMIT.  Then, run

```
git diff $OLD_COMMIT -- enumerate.c every/one.c of/your.c changed/files.c > patch
```

Check that `patch` looks OK, and run `git reset --hard` to throw away all changes in your working copy.  Then carefully try to apply the patch using the `patch` command on top the HEAD.  Voila!

Answer (score 0):

See also [How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git);
use [git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) to stash the changes. You can delete the stash if you don't need to keep the changes;

```
git stash save
git stash drop
```