# Retrieve missing files from remote repo?

Tags: git, repository, git-remote

I accidentally deleted a few files from my local git repo.

I have not pushed this change to the remote.

Is there a easy way to get these files back from the remote?

Normally I would just do a `git clone` but it seems there should be a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git checkout .
```

[How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52704/#52713)

Comment: `git checkout filename` will restore the single file

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to either revert the commit with the deletions, or reset `HEAD` to the commit before you did the deletes, depending on whether you want to keep the deletions in the history or not.

Alternatively, if you haven't committed the deletes yet, you can just checkout the deleted files to restore them from your local repo.

Answer (score 1):

To discard all local changes, you can do:

```
git checkout .
```

To avoid losing local changes, do this instead:

```
git ls-files -d -z | xargs -0 git checkout --
```

(Taken from http://data.agaric.com/restore-locally-deleted-files-git
They also suggest using `git update -- .` but that is not a valid git command.)