# Why does git stash pop say that it could not restore untracked files from stash entry?

Tags: git, git-stash

I had a bunch of staged and unstaged changes and I wanted to quickly switch to another branch and then switch back.

So I staged my changes using:

```
$ git stash push -a
```

(In hindsight I probably could have used `--include-untracked` instead of `--all`)

Then when I went to pop the stash I get a whole lot of errors along the lines of:

```
$ git stash pop
foo.txt already exists, no checkout
bar.txt already exists, no checkout
...
Could not restore untracked files from stash entry
```

There doesn't seem to be any changes restored from the stash.

I also tried `$ git stash branch temp` but that shows the same errors.

I did figure out a way around this which was to use:

```
$ git stash show -p | git apply
```

Disaster averted for now but this raises some questions.

Why did this error happen in the first place and how do I avoid it next time?

Comment: I had to use: `git stash show -p | git apply --3`

Comment: Thanks @xmedeko, can anyone tell the difference between 
git stash show -p | git apply and
git stash show -p | git apply --3 ?

Comment: If you panic, just list your stashed files with `git stash show` and than rescue files one by one: `$ git show stash@{0}:your/stashed/file.txt  >  your_rescued_file.txt`. This will get file from stash and save it under a different name. Now you are safe to experiment with proper rescue methods (see below answers). If things go astray, you always have your rescued files as a last resource.

Comment: Wow, thanks @xmedeko! Once again your comment was the only thing that worked, and it was so simple. +1!

Comment: `git stash show -p` didn't show the untracked file in my case. [Erik Koopmans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55799386/2054512) helped by pointing out `git checkout stash^3 -- .` +1

Comment: You can use `git stash show -p -u` to show the entire stash (including untracked files) and `git stash show -p -u | git apply --3` to restore the entire stash (including untracked files)

Comment: I have the same issue. of 1000 source files, I had heavily edited 6 and created (untracked) 10.  I did git stash --all, then git stash pop with no git commands or file edits between (only did a build to see if worked without my new code).  It reported all 1000 files as "already exist, no checkout" and ended with "error: could not restore untracked files from stash". Looking at the resultant mess, the untracked (new) files seemed to have been restored (so error message is wrong), but none of the edits I did to the tracked files were.  This is a disaster - a lot of work lost.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

As a bit of additional explanation, note that `git stash` makes either two commits, or three commits.  The default is two; you get three if you use any spelling of the `--all` or `--include-untracked` options.

These two, or three, commits are special in one important way: they are on *no* branch.  Git locates them through the special name `stash`.<sup>1</sup>  The most important thing, though, is what Git lets you—and *makes* you—do with these two or three commits.  To understand this we need to look at what's in those commits.

#### What's inside a stash

Every commit can list one or more *parent* commits.  These form a graph, where later commits point back to earlier ones.  The stash normally holds two commits, which I like to call `i` for the index / staging-area contents, and `w` for the work-tree contents.  Remember also that each commit holds a snapshot.  In a normal commit, this snapshot is made *from* the index / staging-area contents.  So the `i` commit is in fact a perfectly normal commit!  It's just not on any branch:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
           |
           i
```

If you're making a normal stash, the `git stash` code makes `w` now by copying all your tracked work-tree files (into a temporary auxiliary index).  Git sets the first parent of this `w` commit to point to the `HEAD` commit, and the second parent to point to commit `i`.  Last, it sets `stash` to point to this `w` commit:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
           |\
           i-w   <-- stash
```

If you add `--include-untracked` or `--all`, Git makes an extra commit, `u`, in between making `i` and `w`.  The snapshot contents for `u` are those files that are untracked but not ignored (`--include-untracked`), or files that are untracked even if they are ignored (`--all`).  This extra `u` commit has *no* parent, and then when `git stash` makes `w`, it sets `w`'s *third* parent to this `u` commit, so that you get:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
           |\
           i-w   <-- stash
            /
           u
```

Git also, at this point, *removes* any work-tree files that wound up in the `u` commit (using `git clean` to do that).

#### Restoring a stash

When you go to *restore* a stash, you have the option of using `--index`, or not using it.  This tells `git stash apply` (or any of the commands that internally use `apply`, such as `pop`) that it should *use* the `i` commit to attempt to modify your current index.  This modification is done with:

```
git diff <hash-of-i> <hash-of-i's-parent> | git apply --index
```

(more or less; there are a bunch of nitty details that get in the way of the basic idea here).

If you omit `--index`, `git stash apply` completely ignores the `i` commit.

If the stash has only two commits, `git stash apply` can now apply the `w` commit.  It does this by calling `git merge`<sup>2</sup> (without allowing it to commit or treat the result as a normal merge), using the original commit on which the stash was made (`i`'s parent, and `w`'s first parent) as the merge base, `w` as the `--theirs` commit, and your current (HEAD) commit as the target of the merge.  If the merge succeeds, all is good—well, at least *Git* thinks so—and the `git stash apply` itself succeeds.  If you used `git stash pop` to apply the stash, the code now *drops* the stash.<sup>3</sup>  If the merge fails, Git declares the apply to have failed.  If you used `git stash pop`, the code retains the stash and delivers the same failure status as for `git stash apply`.

But if you have that *third* commit—if there is a `u` commit in the stash you are applying—then things change!  **There is no option to pretend that the `u` commit does not exist.**<sup>4</sup>  Git insists on extracting all the files *from* that `u` commit, into the current work-tree.  This means the files must either not exist at all, or have the same contents as in the `u` commit.

To make that happen, you can use `git clean` yourself—but remember that untracked files (ignored or not) have no other existence inside a Git repository, so be sure these files can all be destroyed!  Or, you can make a temporary directory, and move the files there for safekeeping—or even do another `git stash save -u` or `git stash save -a`, since those will run `git clean` for you.  But that just leaves you with another `u`-style stash to deal with later.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is in fact `refs/stash`.  This matters if you make a branch named `stash`: the branch's full name is `refs/heads/stash`, so these are not in conflict.  But don't do that: *Git* won't mind, but you will confuse yourself. :-)

<sup>2</sup>The `git stash` code actually uses `git merge-recursive` directly here.  This is necessary for multiple reasons, and also has the side effect of making sure Git does not treat it as a merge when you resolve conflicts and commit.

<sup>3</sup>This is why I recommend avoiding `git stash pop`, in favor of `git stash apply`.  You get a chance to review what got applied, and decide whether it was *actually* applied correctly.  If not, you *still have your stash* which means you can use `git stash branch` to recover everything perfectly.  Well, assuming the lack of that pesky `u` commit.

<sup>4</sup>There really should be: `git stash apply --skip-untracked` or something.  There should also be a variant that means *drop all those `u` commit files into a new directory*, e.g., `git stash apply --untracked-into <dir>`, perhaps.

Comment: Wow! You deserve a medal! Is there any book which you would recommend for such detailed git explanations? Awesome! ‍♂️

Comment: @seelts Unfortunately, Git is sort of continuously evolving, so books get out of date quickly. But Git should be understood as a set of tools—commands that manipulate a commit-ful of files, or manipulate the commit graph, or whatever—that you assemble into whatever is useful to *you*, and not too many books seem to approach it that way either.

Comment: I fail to understand the solution to the problem. Is it just adding `--index`: `git stash apply --index`?

Comment: @Danijel: No. The solution depends on the current state of your work-tree. Given a third commit in a three-commit stash—one that contains untracked files—Git cannot unstash the untracked files if the work-tree has existing files in the way of these untracked files. The files in the work-tree that cause this problem may themselves be either tracked or untracked. It is their existence in the work-tree that presents the problem.

Comment: (The description gets messy because *untracked*, in general, means *present in the work-tree but not in the index*. However, the *stash* holds *three* commits, one of which represents *an* index, so suddenly we have to consider two different index states.)

Comment: Thanks @torek. I first did `git stash save --all`, then I immediately did `git stash apply`, but some files were missing because I renamed them and then created again (before stashing). What helped was: `git checkout stash@{0} -- .` I won't even bother with `git checkout stash^3 -- .` because all seems OK now. It's a pitty I don't have time to really understand what was going on. Thanks.

Comment: @torek what is the meaning of "Git cannot unstash the untracked files if the work-tree has existing files in the way of these untracked files."?

Comment: @user1169587: it means what it says. Maybe an example would help. Suppose the third `u` commit contains a file named `path/to/file` (with some content). Suppose further that your work-tree *already has a file named `path/to/file`* in it. Extracting the content of the `u` commit would *replace* your existing file contents with new contents, destroying whatever work you had in the file named `path/to/file`. So Git won't do that. You'll have to destroy these contents yourself first (by removing the file entirely), or move them out of harm's way (by moving the file).

Comment: @torek "Extracting the content of the u commit would replace your existing file contents with new contents, destroying whatever work you had in the file named path/to/file." 

why git cannot merge the content of _path/to/file_ in u commit to work-tree _path/to/file_ content? because work-tree _path/to/file_ local change has not committed yet? 
so the error message is "Could not restore untracked files from stash entry", "untracked files" means "change but not yet committed file in working tree"?

Comment: The reason Git can't merge the `u` commit with your existing untracked files is that a merge operation requires *three* sets of files, not just two. See [Why is a 3-way merge advantageous over a 2-way merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/1256452) for background. Untracked files are, in general, not in Git at all; these extra `u` commits are an exception to that rule.

Answer (score 222):

I managed to recreate your issue. It seems if you stash untracked files and then you create those files (in your example, `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`), then you have local changes to untracked files that would be overwritten when you apply `git stash pop`.

To get around this issue, you can use the following command. This will **override any unsaved local changes** so be careful.

```
git checkout stash -- .
```

[Here is some further information I found on the previous command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606203/force-git-stash-to-overwrite-added-files).

Comment: My working tree was definitely clean although there could have been changes to ignored files.

Comment: Looks like using `--all`/`-a` [will include ignored files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_options), so that may be relevant.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the same logic applies to ignored files and mark this as the answer (although I think the `git merge --squash --strategy-option=theirs stash` approach is better in this case).

Comment: Agreed, I like that second approach! Good luck with your work!

Comment: This was helpful but it didn't restore *untracked* files - if you have the same problem (`already exists, no checkout`), check my answer below.

Comment: not clear what exacly is checked out in the command, the **last** stash, **all** the stashes?

Comment: Not sure how many times I come to look for your answer

Answer (score 66):

To expand on [Daniel Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51275841/4080966): that code only restores the **tracked** files, even if you used `--include-untracked` (or `-u`) when creating the stash. The full code required is:

```sh
git checkout stash -- .
git checkout stash^3 -- .
git stash drop

# Optional to unstage the changes (auto-staged by default).
git reset
```

This fully restores the tracked contents (in `stash`) and untracked contents (in `stash^3`), then deletes the stash. A few notes:

- **Be careful** - this will overwrite everything with your stash contents!
- Restoring the files with `git checkout` causes them all to become staged automatically, so I've added `git reset` to unstage everything.
- Some resources use `stash@{0}` and `stash@{0}^3`, in my testing it works the same with or without `@{0}`

**Sources:**

- [Force git stash to overwrite added files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16625128/4080966) (linked in Daniel Smith's answer)
- [How can I checkout an untracked file in a git stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23609023/4080966) (info about the magic `stash^3` commit)
- [Atlassian guide to git stash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash) (check "How git stash works" for details on the internal commits)

Comment: Why would you delete the stash, why not just leave it there for a while for safety reasons?

Comment: @Danijel Sure you could keep the stash - depends on your use case I guess. For my purposes I was done with the stash once it was restored.

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever that `refs/stash` doesn't include the untracked files. What a ridiculous violation of intuition.

Answer (score 14):

apart of other answers, I did a little trick

- **Deleted all new files** (already existing files, e.g. foo.txt and bar.txt in the question)
- `git stash apply` (can use any command e.g. apply, pop etc.)

Comment: Not working.. the Deleted Files just appear again at stash apply.. and so does the error!

Comment: just commit the files after delete them, if they were already committed

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to get past this issue is to rename the existing conflicting file to a non-conflicting one.

For example, if you run `git stash apply/pop` and get:

```sh
foo.md already exists, no checkout
error: could not restore untracked files from stash
```

Try rename `foo.md` to `foo.new.md` and rerun `git stash apply/pop`, you won't get the error this time and will have both `foo.md` and `foo.new.md` at your disposal.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue. Since the answers above didn't work without losing files from the stash, I improvised.

My stash, made using `git stash -u`, had untracked newly added files. Some of these files came from code generation, and got committed separately to the master branch before I tried to pop the stash. When I did pop my stash, I got the following:

```
> git stash pop
web-app/src/app/rest-services/api/models/model1.ts already exists, no checkout
web-app/src/app/rest-services/api/models/model2.ts already exists, no checkout
web-app/src/app/rest-services/api/models/model3.ts already exists, no checkout
web-app/src/app/rest-services/api/models/model4.ts already exists, no checkout
error: could not restore untracked files from stash
```

Under the theory that git was unable to merge 2 different new files, I deleted each of the named files in my working directory. I was then able to apply the full stash without missing files or errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I have done to make it work:

1. I deleted each file mentioned in the message in my working directory.
2. I re-applied the stash as unstaged.

All files in the stash should be applied without any errors.

Comment: I like this approach, but for me it lists around 1000 files as" already exists, no checkout" for no reason.  In my stash I only had 6 changed files and 10 new (untracked files).

Answer (score 0):

Once you stash your branch named as (Local Branch) with your local changes. Lets assume File A, File B and newly added File C. File C is in untrack stage while stashing the code on your branch.

Later, if one do git pull to get latest code form master and File A is updated. Afterwards, one tries to apply the stash in the branch but it wouldn't give untracked files i.e. File C because of conflict in File A as it was updated while doing pull request. This is a limitation in new version of GIT.

**Workaround or solution** : point your Local branch head where File A is not updated and apply stash code and now you have control of all three files convert untrack to track file or take a copy of it whatever suits you. update your branch head with git pull command and you have your own code too (can get it from stash or can paste manually if you copied)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem within Visual Studio. When trying the same with GitKraken, I could pop the stash without problems. So it seems to depend on the git client.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a piece of advice because none of the answers really solved my problem, although many got me on the right path to do so.

In my case the non-restored file was:

- untracked when saved in stash
- present and tracked in the current branch

So, the difference between OP situation and mine, was that the file has already been committed in the current branch, instead of being part of unsaved local changes.

I ran into this situation after switching between two branches, of which one did not contain the file, saving and restoring stashes.

Therefore, I had no simple way to get rid of it like `git clean`.

Instead, I did the following:

- I deleted the file
- I staged the deletion
- I restored the stash, this time it worked fine
- I staged the file restored from stash
- I finally unstaged it to restore my initial status

Hope it helps.