# how can one determine the origin of a git stash

Tags: git

I'm having problems of doing

```
git stash pop
```

because of some dos2unix problems. I want to return to working on the stash without having to merge entire files which only differ only by line endings.
I was thinking of returning to the stash after doing

```
git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

but I don't know how to determine the BRANCHNAME which represents the origin of this stash.
Anybody any clue?

Answer (score 7):

#### TL;DR

Use `git stash branch` to *create a new branch* and apply the stash:

```
git stash branch newbranch
```

This always works (well, as long as your current status is all clean: see the long section below) and is the equivalent of creating a new branch whose parent is the commit that was current when you made the stash, then running `git apply --index` (meaning it restores the index and work-tree separately).

#### A literal answer to the question

All you need to do is find out whether any branch name(s) identify the same commit as the parent of the stash in question, so:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' \
    --points-at $(git rev-parse refs/stash~1) refs/heads
```

will find the possible branch name(s), if there are any.  (This relies on relatively modern features of `git for-each-ref`.)

#### Long

Each stash is itself just two, or sometimes three, commits.  What `git stash` does is that it makes these two (or three) commits, but puts them on *no* branch.

The word *branch* in Git is itself a bit ambiguous (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)), but here, we're using it in the sense that a branch *name* like `master` or `develop` simply points to the *last* commit on its branch:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H   <-- develop
```

When you `git checkout` a branch name like `develop`, you are telling Git to:

1. Extract the content of that commit into the *index* (the place where you build the next commit, also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*)
2. Take the now-unfrozen, but still Git-form / compressed files out of the index and copy them into the *work-tree* where you can work on them.
3. Attach the name `HEAD` to the branch name, so that Git knows which commit you have checked out now:

   ```
   ...--E--F--G   <-- master
            \
             H   <-- develop (HEAD)
   ```

   Now Git knows that the commit whose hash is `H` is the current or `HEAD` commit, as pointed-to by the name `develop`.

If you make an ordinary new commit at this point (by copying updated or new files from the work-tree back into the index / staging-area, then running `git commit` to freeze them into a new commit), Git writes the new commit with the current commit as its parent, and then *updates the branch name:*

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` remains attached to the branch name, but now the branch name identifies commit `I` instead of commit `H`.

What `git stash` does is to make *two* commits—one for the index, and one for the work-tree—that *don't have a branch name*.  Instead, Git uses the name `refs/stash` to find the `w` commit (and `w` finds both the original commit and the `i` commit):

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H   <-- develop (HEAD)
          |\
          i-w   <-- refs/stash
```

After saving the `i` and `w` commits, `git stash` runs `git reset --hard`, to set the index and work-tree back to matching the current commit (here, `H`).

In this case, at this point in time, the parent commit of the stash is also pointed-to by the existing branch name `develop`.  But suppose you have done this `git stash`, and then gone on to make a *different* set of changes and made a new commit `I`?  Then you have:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I   <-- develop (HEAD)
          |\
          i-w   <-- refs/stash
```

There is now *no* branch name pointing to existing, historical commit `H`, even though that's the one commit where `refs/stash` is guaranteed to apply.

So, if your index and work-tree are now clean (i.e., match the contents of commit `I`, to which `HEAD` is attached), and you now run `git stash branch recover`, what `git stash` will do is attach a *new* branch name, `recover`, to commit `H`, and check out that commit and make the new branch the current branch by attaching `HEAD` to it:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H   <-- recover (HEAD)
           \
            I   <-- develop
```

and, as the last step of the `git stash branch` operation, apply and drop the stash, so that the index is back to the way the index was when you had `H` checked out and ran `git stash`, and the work-tree is back to the way the work-tree was when you had `H` checked out and ran `git stash`.  You can now finish `git add`ing and `git commit` to make new commit `J`:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--J   <-- recover (HEAD)
           \
            I   <-- develop
```

#### What if `develop` still points to commit `H`?

If you *haven't* moved the previous branch, well, now you have a new branch anyway.  That is, now instead of the above drawing, you would have:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H   <-- develop
           \
            J   <-- recover (HEAD)
```

(I left the new commit as `J` here to make it easier to match it up with the earlier diagram).  There's nothing wrong with this setup.  Of course if you don't *want* the `recover` branch here, you don't have to use `git stash branch`, but it does still work.

#### What about the three-commit stash?

Three-commit stashes are those made by `git stash save -a` (`--all`) or `git stash save -u` (`--include-untracked`).  Applying (or popping) such a stash requires that the files in the third commit not collide with files in the work-tree.  In general, this means the work-tree must not only be "clean" according to `git status`, but also clean in the sense provided by running `git clean` with appropriate options.  In this particular case, even `git stash branch` can fail sometimes.  If it does fail, it leaves the stash un-popped.

For more, see [Why does git stash pop say that it could not restore untracked files from stash entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51275777/1256452)

Comment: How does `git stash` work? *Hopefully my comment can give this answer and its excellent digression enough SEO juice to move it up in search results.*

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Would you mind seeing if you can clarify on my similar question here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62867041/470749

Answer (score 1):

`git stash list` will probably give you what you want.

If you saved your stash with `git stash save` or `git stash push`, then git added a comment to the stash which includes the branch name and the specific commit:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 039142b Initial commit
```

Even if you gave your stash a custom name, git still saves the branch name:

```
$ git stash save "My stash"
Saved working directory and index state On master: My stash

$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On master: My stash
```