# Not able to Apply git stashed changes to Current branch

Tags: git

Consider I had to work on Branch **Y** but I was working on the branch **X** and I committed all my changes to **X**. These changes need to be committed on branch **Y**. Somehow I reverted all the changes from the Branch **X** and stashed them. Now I moved to branch **Y** and I want to apply the stashed changes to my current branch i.e **Y**.

I can see my stashed in stash list but when I am trying to apply stash by the following command  :

```
git stash apply 1
git stash apply stash@{1}
git stash apply "stash@{1}"
```

I am getting the message as "nothing to commit".

There were some untracked files on branch **X** so I stashed them using following command:

```
git stash --include-untracked
```

Comment: Try `git stash list` to show all the stage his. make sure you're in the right branch

Comment: @PatrickChen I have switched the branch. i stashed changes on branch X and now i want to apply them on Y

Comment: use `git stash pop` instead, while on branch Y

Comment: there was no need to stash the untracked, as you'll find them untracked on both branches.

Comment: @DaemonPainter It was not allowing me to move branch until stashing untracked files.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Using `git stash pop` Can i get 0 and 1 index changes?

Comment: [yes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: @DaemonPainter `git stash pop` showing an error: **Could not restore untracked files from stash entry**

Comment: that was expected, reason is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275777/why-does-git-stash-pop-say-that-it-could-not-restore-untracked-files-from-stash)

Comment: if you haven't solved, you can try to commit on branch Y, switch to branch X, cherrypick the commit in Y, switch back to branch Y, revert the commit.  
This gonna be a little tricky, but should work.

Comment: @YusefMaali Next time I will try with your solution