# git stash apply restores only new files

Tags: git, git-stash

On some point of developing I used `git stash save --all` to stash my progress. But then, when I try to apply this stash: `git stash apply stash@{0}` it only get back new files, but files that were modified  previously are not changed. It also shows message at the end: `Could not restore untracked files from stash`. That is interesting because actually untracked files are the only that were backed up.

If I run `git stash show stash@{0}` it shows me the files that were only edited, so edit files are not gone anywhere and they are still inside this stash.

How I can restore *all* the files, both untracked and modified?

Comment: Had the same error. I could solve it when I made a hard reset to the last commit on the branch and applied the stash again. Then I got all files from the stash (new and untracked files).

Comment: @Philj0 didn`t help..

Comment: What does `git stash show` shows? And you should look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586009/how-to-recover-from-git-stash-save-all/20589663#20589663

Comment: @Philj0 diff between state of current files and files that are in stash

Comment: to stash the untracked files you have to use the  `-u` Parameter to include untracked files. (Sorry, I did not read your question correctly)
You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586009/how-to-recover-from-git-stash-save-all/20589663#20589663 for further information

Comment: @Philj0 I got my file changes back finally.. Here is what helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508919/4512509 .