# Can I override working copy by index content?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you discard unstaged changes in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

I know that when I `git add` tracking content to repository, git copy/update content of its object stores. If I change my content continuously without `git add` again, and **I regrets all those changes and I want my last snapshot in index back to my working copy**, how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git-checkout` for this:

```
git checkout -- .
```

Comment: Alright,I got clear concept finally. Git's checkout behavior is override my working copy with index content actuallly, not my last commit(usually HEAD). Thanks, ThiefMaster.