# Cannot see the unstaged changes git filter-branch is complaining about

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

On a new repo clone, `git filter-branch` complains that I have unstaged changes, e.g.

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter plugins/hypervisors/hyperv -- --all 
Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
```

However, these `git status` says that there are no changes:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Where do I look to find out what the changes are?

Comment: If this is an open source tool, why not provide the link to the repo so we can test it out?

Comment: AFAIK, the problem lies with my local system.  However, the repo is on github (lafferty/cshv3).

Comment: It worked for me: http://pastebin.com/p7e6Eun9. So the problem really is somewhere on your system. Try the whole operation again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by wiping the stash, e.g.

```
git stash drop
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719/939250)

Would be interesting to know where the changes to the stash came from.