# Error in using Julia packages

Tags: windows, julia, julia-studio

I am using Julia Studio 0.4.4 in Win 7. After installing TimeData, when I write:

```
  using TimeData
```

I get this error:

```
 LoadError("C:\\Users\\user\\.julia\\TimeData\\src\\TimeData.jl",14,ErrorException("DataFrame not defined"))
```

If I write:

```
 using DataFrames
```

I get another error:

```
 LoadError("C:\\Users\\user\\.julia\\TimeData\\src\\TimeData.jl",14,ErrorException("invalid redefinition of constant Timedata"))
```

Here is what  Pkg.status() says:

```
- TimeData                      0.0.1              8e216472 (dirty)
 - TimeModels                    0.0.1
 - TimeSeries                    0.2.0
Additional packages:
 - BinDeps                       0.2.12
 - Blocks                        0.0.4
 - Cairo                         0.2.13
 - Color                         0.2.10
 - DataArrays                    0.0.3
 - DataFrames                    0.4.3
 - Datetime                      0.1.3
 - GZip                          0.2.12
 - HTTPClient                    0.1.0
 - IniFile                       0.2.2
 - LibCURL                       0.1.3
 - LibExpat                      0.0.4
 - SortingAlgorithms             0.0.1
 - StatsBase                     0.3.8
 - Tk
```

Comment: Same thing happen after `Pkg.update()`?

Comment: Yes, even after Pkg.update(). I removed and reinstalled TimeData a few times.

Comment: What's the directory listing of `C:\Users\user\.julia`?  Do you have other package problems?

Comment: Well, TimeModels fails too when typing using, but others work.

Comment: C:\Users\user\.julia has the list of packages. Apparently, things are fine.

Comment: Does it work using the commandline, that is, **not** Julia Studio?

Comment: How about augmenting your original post with the output of `Pkg.status()`.

Comment: I have errors when using commandline too.

Comment: My `Pkg.status()` shows a number of updated packages, e.g., ` - TimeData                      0.1.2` & ` - DataArrays                    0.1.10` & others.  How confident are you in your Julia and Julia package installs?

Answer (score 1):

Julia Pkg.update() will not update a package is dirty(some files is changed or did not at the right branch).

`- TimeData                      0.0.1              8e216472 (dirty)`

this should mean you have changed the TimeData package.

so please go to C:\Users\user\.julia\TimeData, and run `git checkout .` this will throw away all changes in files from the current directory downwards([How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)). Then try Pkg.update() .