# git switch from branch back to master

Tags: git

I'm new to git, below is my step, and want to know if I switch back to master why I see same thing modified on browser?

```
cd ../project location
git init
git add *
git commit -m 'without style'

git branch 'style-a'
git checkout 'style-a'
git show-branch -a
```

output

```
! [master] without style
 * [style-a] without style
--
+* [master] without style
```

... after I modified code inside file

and

```
git add *
```

then

```
git checkout master
```

why still get same thing on browser? do I miss something?

does use switch means I can switch to different branch or master to get each group updated code?

UPDATE

`git status`

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   ...
    more new file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you discard unstaged changes in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Comment: @Basilevs  I still can't get it..  and I don't want delete the branch just wanna see the code before, what should I do?

Comment: What does `git status` give you?  If it doesn't say "Working directly clean", you've still got unstaged changes floating about.

Comment: I update git status result in question. unstaged changes floating about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `style-a` branch you are on `master`. Creating a branch in Git will start the new branch from where you currently were.

More precisely, you were on `master` and created a commit. So, your `HEAD` was pointing to the tip of the master branch. Then, you created a branch, and switched to it. But your `HEAD` is still pointing to the same commit as it was before because **no new content was committed on `style-a`**.

`style-a` is pointing to the same commit as `master`. This is why you are not seeing any new code changes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. so what is the correct step to get what I want : keep original files, and make changes to store on different new group (then I can make different version), and switch different version see each one

Comment: @user1575921 your terminology is not quite clear, but create commits on different branches depending on the use-case for that branch, and switch between branches with the checkout command, such as "git checkout master"

Comment: does that mean if I switch `style-a` make change code and do `git add *` and `git commit`  then switch back to master will see original version?  I have to commit under branch `style-a`, right?

Comment: @user1575921 correct...your commit will belong to the branch that you are currently on. Committing on style-a will have no effect on master

Comment: after `git checkout 'style-a'` , `git commit -m 'change'` and `git switch master`   not work, still same result like 'style-a' ..

Comment: @user1575921 before you did your commit was there content staged and ready to be comitted? Did you do a "git add _filename_" first?

Comment: @user1575921 rather than "git add *" please pass the name of the file you are trying to stage, for example: "git add src/foo.txt". Also, prior to the add, are you sure that there were changes made to files in your local repo?

Comment: but if there are a lot lot files I have to add each path? and sure I make change to the files..

Comment: @user1575921 yes...you can use wildcards, but I wanted to make sure you knew not to just always use the "*" or ".". I very commonly just do a "git add ."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to temporarily switch to master just to look at the code you had, you can run `git stash` before switching branches to hide the work you currently have in progress ("unstaged changes"). Then when you switch back to your new branch, you can use `git stash apply` to bring your in-progress work back.

When you're ready to save your work, make sure you have the branch you want to save your work to checked out. Use `git add <filename>` to stage changes to a file (get them ready to save), and `git commit` to save your work to your branch.

Comment: thanks for reply , do I need to `switch` to `master` or `style-a` then do `git stash`?

Comment: You can use `git stash` anytime, although it's recommended you stash changes before switching branches.

Comment: it works, then if I want to create more then one group/version like `master` `style-a` `style-b` use git stash how to switch to

Comment: You can create (`git branch`) and switch to (`git checkout`) your `style-b` branch in the same way you did `style-a`. The `stash` command just temporarily sets aside your changes until you bring them back; you can switch between whatever branches you want. If your changes are intended for `style-a` switch back to that branch before using `git stash apply`.

Comment: I create branch `style-a` and make change then `add *`, `commit -m '..'` then switch back to `master` still same result.. do I miss somethin

Comment: What "same result"? 1. Do you mean your new code, that you committed to `style-a`, appears on `master`? 2. If you run `git status`, does it show any unstaged changes? If you run `git log` on each branch, is the commit history different?

Comment: Thanks!! it working now. and the `stash` usage explanation!