# Undo everything and return to last commit

Tags: git, github

Can you tell me how i can undo every change i have made since my last commit, delete anything newer and return to my last commit?

Neither git checkout df60bb or git reset HEAD --hard worked . At least one file (RoR migration file) which wasnt part of the last commit remains after these two commands

Thanks

Comment: Define "neither worked".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you discard unstaged changes in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

First, go back to the root directory of your project. Then, do

```
git reset HEAD .
git checkout -- .
```

What this will do is unstage any changes that are currently staged, and then undo any unstaged changes to *tracked* files. To delete untracked files, do:

```
rm $(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard)
```

Which will find all the files and then shell-expand them for deletion.

It should also be noted that, if you have files that are being *generated*, it's usually a good idea to add them to your `.gitignore` file so you don't have to constantly be deleting them.