# Undo changes made to files

Tags: git

I have the master branch of my repository checked out. It has the following 4 files.

1. One.txt
2. Two.txt
3. Three.txt
4. Four.txt

While reading each of these files, I ended up making small but unintentional changes to **Two.txt** and **Four.txt**. These changes are of the nature of adding line breaks or spaces or removing some of them. It wouldn't hurt to check them in but I'd rather not.

I am still in the master branch and I'd like to undo the changes I made to these two files.

When I do:

```
$ git status
```

It reads:

> Changes not staged for commit.
>
> Two.txt
>
> Four.txt

I understand that unless I git add them, the changes to these files will be un-tracked and hence will not be considered for commits.

But I'd still like to rollback changes I made to these files and get the real version that I downloaded.

I did:

```
$ git checkout
```

But that didn't make the red go away.

Then I did:

```
$ git pull
```

So it would fetch and merge from the remote master into my local master but that didn't overwrite the changes I made to **Two.txt** and **Four.txt**.

How do I overwrite the changes I made to **Two.txt** and **Four.txt** with the original content that the remote repo's master had?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reset all the changes you made

```
 git checkout -f
```

In case you want to checkout only unstaged changes instead

```
git checkout -- .
```

Comment: Thank you. 11 more minutes.

Comment: Sure. My Pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

To undo changes either you use `checkout`

```
git checkout -- Two.txt Four.txt
```

Or if your workspace is clean and doesn't contain any new changes that you don't want to loose, in this case you can use `reset --hard` that will force the commit you tell it

```
# I want the version of HEAD
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Be careful, this will apply the version of `HEAD` to all the files of your project

Another helpful command `stash`

```
 # To move changes from the workspace
 git stash
 # Delete that stash
 git stash pop
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation.

Comment: if you do a git checkout -- two.txt and decide you want to go back how is this done?