# PhpStorm revert changed files from vendor

Tags: git, phpstorm, vendor

For testing I have changed some files in vendor but now can not find the correct files which I have changed. I don't want to delete and reinstall vendor, I want to revert all changes.

Any suggestions on how to find all changed files in vendor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to use git, so you can right click on the vendor folder, click `Git` then `Revert...` and choose the files you want revert.

I would also recommend to change your PhpStorm setting as follows: Go to settings and then `Version Control` then tick the checkbox for `Show directories with changed descendants`. Now you see which folders/files are changed in your Project Explorer on the left side.