# Is it possible to discard unstaged Git changes to files NOT matching a pattern?

Tags: git

I know to use `git checkout .` and similar as explained here [How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git) but would like to know if it is possible to carry out "negative" discarding.

That is, discard unstaged changes to files that DO NOT match a set of extensions.

So instead of `git checkout -- "*.ext".` to discard changes to *.ext files, is it possible to do a sort of `git checkout -- !(*.extA|*.extB|*.extC|*.extP)"`. when I have changes to *.extA to *.extZ files in place.

That is, to only be left with changes to the *.extA, *.extB, *.extC and *.extP files.

Is this possible at all and if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use path exclusions

```
git checkout -- . `:!*.extA' ':!*.extB' ':!*.extC' ':!*.extP'
```