# How I can completely discard or remove this change

Tags: git, github

```
git status

On branch devel

Your branch is up to date with 'origin/devel'.

Changes not staged for commit:

(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)

(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

      modified:   DigitalExperience/Excels/names/customer(New)
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

How I can completely discard this change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the text you quoted, except for one possible stumbling block:

> ```
> (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
> ```

Hence:

```
git checkout -- "DigitalExperience/Excels/names/customer(New)"
```

is likely to do the trick.  You may need some other kind of quote marks (single quotes), or no quote marks at all, depending on your command-line interpreter.

The problem here is that the file's name includes parentheses.  This file is named:

```
DigitalExperience/Excels/names/customer(New)
```

complete with opening and closing parentheses, and some command-line interpreters treat those specially.

Comment: I used

     > git checkout -- "DigitalExperience/Excels/names/customer(New)"

But its does not delete the chngeses

Comment: In that case: (1) Are you on a case-insensitive file system such as the default Windows or MacOS file system? (2) If so, is there another file in the commit with a name that differs only in case, probably created on a Linux system? (3) Are you using `.gitattributes` and/or `core.autocrlf` to change line endings in the work-tree? (4) What version of Git are you using?