# How to discard unstaged file mode changes in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

`git diff` result is following.

```
>git diff
diff --git a/.husky/commit-msg b/.husky/commit-msg
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
diff --git a/.husky/pre-commit b/.husky/pre-commit
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
diff --git a/deploy/build.sh b/deploy/build.sh
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
diff --git a/deploy/container2local.sh b/deploy/container2local.sh
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
diff --git a/scripts/capture_all_test.sh b/scripts/capture_all_test.sh
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
diff --git a/src/hooks/useFuse.ts b/src/hooks/useFuse.ts
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
diff --git a/src/hooks/useSortableData.ts b/src/hooks/useSortableData.ts
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

`git status` result is following.

```
On branch feature/NFTmarketplace
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/NFTmarketplace'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .husky/commit-msg
        modified:   .husky/pre-commit
        modified:   deploy/build.sh
        modified:   deploy/container2local.sh
        modified:   scripts/capture_all_test.sh
        modified:   src/hooks/useFuse.ts
        modified:   src/hooks/useSortableData.ts

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

There is no content difference, but only mode difference.
I want to discard these changes. I did all approaches on [How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

But none of them works.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please, post the output of `git status`.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca, I added `git status` result to post.

Comment: Well, the brute-force approach should always work: `git ls-files -m -z | xargs -0 chmod 755`

Comment: "None of them works" is unclear, could you elaborate? If you still see the same status/diff output, it *could* be that said methods worked, but the same cause (some settings in your IDE? Something else?) changed it back again. Not saying it's the case, but to be considered/examined.

Comment: @RomainValeri, your comment is very interesting. Could the OS difference cause this problem? I am currently using Windows 10, but I am not sure the original project was developed on which OS.

Comment: Not just the OS per se, I doubt it. I'm working with similar conditions (Linux VM hosted on a Windows10, all files LF in the project) and it's fine.

Comment: Windows in general does not support Linux-style permissions. Git should have detected this and should have configured your Git repository with `core.filemode` set to `false`. If your Windows system *does* support Linux-style file permissions, the `chmod` in @Boldewyn's comment should fix things; if not, figure out why `core.filemode` is set to `true` instead of `false`, and set it to `false` for now but figure out if you're sharing a Git repository across OSes (a very bad idea!).