# Xcode 14.1 automatically modifies the project.pbxproj file. How to discard this change?

Tags: xcode, git, atlassian-sourcetree, xcode14

I am running one iOS/Swift project in Xcode 14.1. Git showing **project.pbxproj** file modified.  A few days back I merged some branches and pushed the changes. The branch is working for others but causing an issue for me. Even I did not modify any file after the push. I want to discard this local change. Please help me.

I tried to remove the changes with help of the following commands.

```
1. $git checkout . 
2. $git clean -d -f
```

The change is disappear for a second after executing `git checkout .` but again shows the same changes after some time. After running the **checkout** terminal show the *Updated 1 path from the index* message. I tried to discard changes from the source tree but after refreshing it again showed modify.

Git difference is showing same file is added and deleted on same folder location.
[image]

Comment: Please show the diff, that might help.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev added image for diff. Anyway I do not want these changes . I want to discard.

Comment: ideally this file should not be in the repo. I know there is not enough tools to manage xcode project changes programatically but it's possible most of the time with e.g. trapeze and node-xcode

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the ways mentioned here
[How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)
But does not work anything for me.

**My Solution:**

Solution 1:

I deleted the repo and took a fresh clone.

**Update**

Found another solution also, most of the time it works for me but in case it does not work for you go for the first solution.

*Step 1:*

Quite the Xcode

*Step 2:*

Discard the project file changes from either terminal using `git checkout .` or any UI tool.

*Step 3:*

Open your Xcode project. Hopefully, you will not get project file changes.